# I need to Input a value from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to input a value from a variable and have scoured the net for weeks looking for a solution.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload=function(){
function updateTotal(){
    var basic = 0.00;
    var add = 0;
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var checkboxes = form.getElementsByClassName('addon');   
    for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i ++) {
       if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
           add += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value, 10);
       }
    }
    var p = basic + add;
    var price = "Total - £" + p ; 
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = price;  
}

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
updateTotal();
```

I also have several of these on the page

```
<input id="cbd8" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="£22">£22 - Add to cart</input>
```

These display a running total within a div

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

The problem arises when I need to use the variable to change the "value" field in a form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="replace-this">
```

Please let me know if this is possible.
Thank you, Mark.

Comment: what is `total` ? id or name or any thing else?

Comment: Your `<input>` does not have an `id="total"`… is that what you're trying to select with `getElementById`?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can access the hidden input just with the name.

So,
Replace

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = price;
```

with

```
document.getElementsByName("amount")[0].value = price;
```

Comment: Is this an answer? The input doesn't have an `id`!

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: ***Note:** In HTML5, the "name" attribute is deprecated and has been replaced by the "id" attribute for many elements. Use the document.getElementById() method where it is appropriate. Also look at the getElementsByClassName() and getElementsByTagName() methods.*